# ScyllaDB : One of the nodes in a 3-node cluster fails to join the cluster after a restart

Tags: scylla

We have a 3 node cluster (single DC) running on Ubuntu 18.04. We had to upgrade all nodes in the cluster (increase the disk space) and hence stopped node-3 first, upgraded the instance and attempted to start it back. It started up after 300 seconds (after failing to connect to the seed nodes), but it has started as a separate cluster. nodetool status on node-3 shows nodes 1 and 2 as down (DN). nodetool status on nodes 1 and 2 show node-3 as down (DN) and 1 and 2 as up (UN).

**Why is node-3 not able to connect to the seed nodes?** Initially when the cluster was created, seeds list was set to only node-1 in all 3 nodes. Before the node-3 was stopped, the seeds list was updated to node-1,node-2,node3. After restart, node-3 is not able to connect to the seed nodes.

**node-3:~$** nodetool status

```
Datacenter: scylla_data_center
==============================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  a.b.c.176  ?          256          ?       b1642399-9596-4bc7-8f01-d875f0584e77  scylla_rack
DN  a.b.c.177  ?          256          ?       e7f6e8f4-c07e-47e7-946d-ba76a272776f  scylla_rack
UN  a.b.c.198  126.83 GB  256          ?       b29ae510-1edc-4ae4-bd4d-fea2de229750  scylla_rack
```

**node-2:~$** nodetool status

```
Datacenter: scylla_data_center
==============================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  a.b.c.176  138.98 GB  256          ?       b1642399-9596-4bc7-8f01-d875f0584e77  scylla_rack
UN  a.b.c.177  128.26 GB  256          ?       e7f6e8f4-c07e-47e7-946d-ba76a272776f  scylla_rack
DN  a.b.c.198  127.66 GB  256          ?       b29ae510-1edc-4ae4-bd4d-fea2de229750  scylla_rack
```

**node-1:~$** nodetool describecluster

```
Cluster Information:
        Name: Scylla_Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
        DynamicEndPointSnitch: disabled
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                224341ff-6870-30a9-b9c2-977007111e00: [a.b.c.177, a.b.c.176]
```

How can I analyze what is the cause for this? Please help.

**Logs from syslog:**

```
Feb 16 05:24:40 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - Connect seeds again ... (299 seconds passed)
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Shadow round failed with std::runtime_error (Unable to gossip with any seeds (ShadowRound)), checking remote features with system tables only
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - Node a.b.c.176 does not contain SUPPORTED_FEATURES in gossip, using features saved in system table, features={COMPUTED_COLUMNS, CORRECT_COUNTER_ORDER, CORRECT_NON_COMPOUND_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, CORRECT_STATIC_COMPACT_IN_MC, COUNTERS, DIGEST_INSENSITIVE_TO_EXPIRY, DIGEST_MULTIPARTITION_READ, HINTED_HANDOFF_SEPARATE_CONNECTION, INDEXES, LARGE_PARTITIONS, LA_SSTABLE_FORMAT, LWT, MATERIALIZED_VIEWS, MC_SSTABLE_FORMAT, NONFROZEN_UDTS, PER_TABLE_PARTITIONERS, RANGE_TOMBSTONES, ROLES, ROW_LEVEL_REPAIR, SCHEMA_TABLES_V3, STREAM_WITH_RPC_STREAM, TRUNCATION_TABLE, UNBOUNDED_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, VIEW_VIRTUAL_COLUMNS, WRITE_FAILURE_REPLY, XXHASH}
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - Node a.b.c.177 does not contain SUPPORTED_FEATURES in gossip, using features saved in system table, features={COMPUTED_COLUMNS, CORRECT_COUNTER_ORDER, CORRECT_NON_COMPOUND_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, CORRECT_STATIC_COMPACT_IN_MC, COUNTERS, DIGEST_INSENSITIVE_TO_EXPIRY, DIGEST_MULTIPARTITION_READ, HINTED_HANDOFF_SEPARATE_CONNECTION, INDEXES, LARGE_PARTITIONS, LA_SSTABLE_FORMAT, LWT, MATERIALIZED_VIEWS, MC_SSTABLE_FORMAT, NONFROZEN_UDTS, PER_TABLE_PARTITIONERS, RANGE_TOMBSTONES, ROLES, ROW_LEVEL_REPAIR, SCHEMA_TABLES_V3, STREAM_WITH_RPC_STREAM, TRUNCATION_TABLE, UNBOUNDED_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, VIEW_VIRTUAL_COLUMNS, WRITE_FAILURE_REPLY, XXHASH}
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - Feature check passed. Local node a.b.c.198 features = {COMPUTED_COLUMNS, CORRECT_COUNTER_ORDER, CORRECT_NON_COMPOUND_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, CORRECT_STATIC_COMPACT_IN_MC, COUNTERS, DIGEST_INSENSITIVE_TO_EXPIRY, DIGEST_MULTIPARTITION_READ, HINTED_HANDOFF_SEPARATE_CONNECTION, INDEXES, LARGE_PARTITIONS, LA_SSTABLE_FORMAT, LWT, MATERIALIZED_VIEWS, MC_SSTABLE_FORMAT, NONFROZEN_UDTS, PER_TABLE_PARTITIONERS, RANGE_TOMBSTONES, ROLES, ROW_LEVEL_REPAIR, SCHEMA_TABLES_V3, STREAM_WITH_RPC_STREAM, TRUNCATION_TABLE, UNBOUNDED_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, VIEW_VIRTUAL_COLUMNS, WRITE_FAILURE_REPLY, XXHASH}, Remote common_features = {COMPUTED_COLUMNS, CORRECT_COUNTER_ORDER, CORRECT_NON_COMPOUND_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, CORRECT_STATIC_COMPACT_IN_MC, COUNTERS, DIGEST_INSENSITIVE_TO_EXPIRY, DIGEST_MULTIPARTITION_READ, HINTED_HANDOFF_SEPARATE_CONNECTION, INDEXES, LARGE_PARTITIONS, LA_SSTABLE_FORMAT, LWT, MATERIALIZED_VIEWS, MC_SSTABLE_FORMAT, NONFROZEN_UDTS, PER_TABLE_PARTITIONERS, RANGE_TOMBSTONES, ROLES, ROW_LEVEL_REPAIR, SCHEMA_TABLES_V3, STREAM_WITH_RPC_STREAM, TRUNCATION_TABLE, UNBOUNDED_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, VIEW_VIRTUAL_COLUMNS, WRITE_FAILURE_REPLY, XXHASH}
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Restarting a node in NORMAL status
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] database - Schema version changed to e0df65b5-0794-39a7-b95f-58df4b065456
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Starting up server gossip
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 4] compaction - Compacting [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1576-big-Data.db:level=0, /var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1564-big-Data.db:level=0, ]
Feb 16 05:24:41 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 4] compaction - Compacted 2 sstables to [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1588-big-Data.db:level=0, ]. 18905 bytes to 12286 (~64% of original) in 54ms = 0.22MB/s. ~256 total partitions merged to 1.
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - No gossip backlog; proceeding
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - Node a.b.c.177 does not contain SUPPORTED_FEATURES in gossip, using features saved in system table, features={COMPUTED_COLUMNS, CORRECT_COUNTER_ORDER, CORRECT_NON_COMPOUND_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, CORRECT_STATIC_COMPACT_IN_MC, COUNTERS, DIGEST_INSENSITIVE_TO_EXPIRY, DIGEST_MULTIPARTITION_READ, HINTED_HANDOFF_SEPARATE_CONNECTION, INDEXES, LARGE_PARTITIONS, LA_SSTABLE_FORMAT, LWT, MATERIALIZED_VIEWS, MC_SSTABLE_FORMAT, NONFROZEN_UDTS, PER_TABLE_PARTITIONERS, RANGE_TOMBSTONES, ROLES, ROW_LEVEL_REPAIR, SCHEMA_TABLES_V3, STREAM_WITH_RPC_STREAM, TRUNCATION_TABLE, UNBOUNDED_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, VIEW_VIRTUAL_COLUMNS, WRITE_FAILURE_REPLY, XXHASH}
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - Node a.b.c.176 does not contain SUPPORTED_FEATURES in gossip, using features saved in system table, features={COMPUTED_COLUMNS, CORRECT_COUNTER_ORDER, CORRECT_NON_COMPOUND_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, CORRECT_STATIC_COMPACT_IN_MC, COUNTERS, DIGEST_INSENSITIVE_TO_EXPIRY, DIGEST_MULTIPARTITION_READ, HINTED_HANDOFF_SEPARATE_CONNECTION, INDEXES, LARGE_PARTITIONS, LA_SSTABLE_FORMAT, LWT, MATERIALIZED_VIEWS, MC_SSTABLE_FORMAT, NONFROZEN_UDTS, PER_TABLE_PARTITIONERS, RANGE_TOMBSTONES, ROLES, ROW_LEVEL_REPAIR, SCHEMA_TABLES_V3, STREAM_WITH_RPC_STREAM, TRUNCATION_TABLE, UNBOUNDED_RANGE_TOMBSTONES, VIEW_VIRTUAL_COLUMNS, WRITE_FAILURE_REPLY, XXHASH}
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature COMPUTED_COLUMNS is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature CORRECT_COUNTER_ORDER is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature CORRECT_NON_COMPOUND_RANGE_TOMBSTONES is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature CORRECT_STATIC_COMPACT_IN_MC is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature COUNTERS is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature DIGEST_INSENSITIVE_TO_EXPIRY is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature DIGEST_MULTIPARTITION_READ is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature HINTED_HANDOFF_SEPARATE_CONNECTION is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature INDEXES is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature LARGE_PARTITIONS is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature LWT is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature MATERIALIZED_VIEWS is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature MC_SSTABLE_FORMAT is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature NONFROZEN_UDTS is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature PER_TABLE_PARTITIONERS is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature RANGE_TOMBSTONES is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature ROLES is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature ROW_LEVEL_REPAIR is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature SCHEMA_TABLES_V3 is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature STREAM_WITH_RPC_STREAM is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature TRUNCATION_TABLE is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] system_keyspace - Got cluster agreement on truncation table feature. Removing legacy records.
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature UNBOUNDED_RANGE_TOMBSTONES is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature VIEW_VIRTUAL_COLUMNS is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature WRITE_FAILURE_REPLY is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] features - Feature XXHASH is enabled
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] system_keyspace - Legacy records deleted.
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting system distributed keyspace
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Using saved tokens {981359583743598234, 914643842153801541, 9010590306704705381, 8978199967542709796, 8823634646786289099, 8796898105082258136, 8735550987922770836, 8716862277181876955, 8409105211318848833, 8377749213602607469, 8368791134507409577, 8279480215642442291, 8226961371913237686, 818381322587006401, 8015510533693741419, 7861744753126011670, 7421129492214354842, 7214971269794117680, 7134961561941729532, 6923641246652266152, 6776104411408891615, 6695671858569773702, 6693992036470326300, 6629009954816350525, 6548856613543647119, 6389196725922261142, 6163371136002122168, 6133043365797828528, 585649641794656355, 5738577221751324225, 5738248321319428204, 5705043832523143106, 5668216508314928077, -4557764141784572195, -1644045961680410408, -7337241265398333233, -843795661146775055, -6302540392497142197, -5833743234028982803, -634705565880395230, -4958499958501506050, -5721899000934394495, -5662226590528258745, -5863550396435924306, 7405132976089028394, -1483338121755382290, -5599651753802208674, -5497935070567060245, -3287241193203949349, -5480724239573015458, -1768913238822924244, -4313920312240004082, -7742269385760950209, 1544104103817535351, -5151210696294284952, -4945370009733546535, -4736232796159710631, 1297334564753141491, -7314483105723765852, 9155415407225907444, -8238109602967798162, -4055299875677524731, -6225897398415140129, -4464250693382842193, -4139729551782525945, -4101875752422732840, -4036058009622413045, -3887089173831867306, -5949312886484657205, -4302826775874228972, 4860225828015527099, -4176767073335097420, -2529787299615517648, -2329419726267129792, 5787431231402222772, -3301430467437933287, -2723124257130426774, -4926578624848477465, 1550847609577933440, -1916156740536922152, 7192748273674972870, -2878270740901973302, -2485123870808844519, 5413629940898600116, -6037901051187131011, -3817121916838484812, -688606435673695662, 8247134048417264463, -5322928324362422086, 4767049724017491120, 3591737829389263358, -38199495392631203, -2115530598853125641, -1170251189550237325, 1751289155726942140, -214498304572404919, 2198492660263745610, -1896243756967692565, 7738028362278836365, -4681327999969571817, -6307738690076505542, -1180128817601957970, -1247294995264304572, -1276317355778147260, -2680829330196023582, -6337067260532457853, -2600503851729509055, -6307321555293480304, 9106645826555318592, 9061774124564711711, -3180210182939961985, -2748991993166122115, 3422651550806358808, -3717690279312985028, -3995930376652802796, 8547898083999725455, -1043835251045960321, -2642715296731302325, -5149132603055791464, -3861004888145475545, 9157071785062909445, 9032911546674574035, 3305983580718934862, -1981477152297299877, -1058782092572298128, 7822587515481166661, -1368605066756232610, 6455877678004719235, -1505957052533080322, -3814037245040110293, -1566295029164646162, -8371461501928103821, -8897274447384318218, -5316828967805419512, 5745484637631331604, -2678930901140445786, -5136598720956101600, -663801927112347845, -6739283263411693711, 1749206398117464736, -3287143799763388087, -2598234819930738431, -4082234711130884355, -9209787921805962716, 3010101704879133373, -1890238888283138344, -7761958934793014252, -8172674007873106523, -739123274252957022, 3265753453995204282, -2915992172628861199, -3667783081752373538, -6501236203315282760, 8931169065516500523, 5533486863258912614, -4919654394039939902, -3395543248856121953, -4970767617117537957, 423393396060418976, -6562888536124186750, 8620915609834225408, -768438852331168683, 3409000770900983238, 4432443222351601018, 6418490594918376620, 4497995499735905959, -6636956636360348345, -6665320506662753578, -5305167683859848462, 3179171907273646765, -2087973484340967048, -6667986014290191580, 4156577717195337895, -3034639017138832321, -6687940317915620534, -6728397100427179352, 1889439023822131084, -3660003847260911784, -6749908253833615569, -4826694828955081272, -6808535190151648746, -5882251120294352269, -6614373203765155209, -7048971061032113655, -7117961121566796258, 2142964552067073128, -7223572769323795131, 9197226287558170824, -7375309003048271910, 85073829603582502, 1283453278591625454, -7492617147315786480, 1388676553039166118, -7682939894669667664, -8137558297361045108, -4041246415814689872, -8345018714663555081, -2783546563957281471, -8791971152774881062, 3101156310359519828, -8380646024208568298, -8670052273494495724, -8670748993509014291, 9144871785596149756, -8689026017675532195, -879492027863855393, -2539032810908864131, -8984181823612140772, -3122711311429953308, -9015557707182576916, -9104214729339575714, 6752494505809604050, -960614186048457472, -6498505452476582165, -7925996298075583396, 3875232282660286389, 1260220645871937735, -1413254618414978453, 1480566843288401576, 4398483809836019694, -6782135258406156880, -7612520485750890120, 2371298605054022667, 6035261906275539740, -784248190169511198, 2508674685785936233, 2659675948217842415, -5053961063111697967, 2724877485090627519, 1864306643481604233, 2876361943714477319, 2888513980906119706, 2895077279165987494, 2916672112075092115, -6837236943880328093, 30200552277592369, 3085579160270189285, 3103812910155078786, 2063390855526692088, 3183184163975239163, -5370407169213155335, 3239379584315210024, 330763901795203252, 3619116542448789429, 4090208882828735628, -3244616077337361530, 4485785961072150850, -5805291180915492837, 4942364365952111313, 8098572163962579030, 5091212439202166244, 660083585913023736, 534770842014008233, 3650585966843974153, 5406231698757539610, 5483719450797787800}
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] database - Schema version changed to 224341ff-6870-30a9-b9c2-977007111e00
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla: message repeated 2 times: [  [shard 0] database - Schema version changed to 224341ff-6870-30a9-b9c2-977007111e00]
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 4] compaction - Compacting [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1600-big-Data.db:level=0, /var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1588-big-Data.db:level=0, ]
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Node a.b.c.198 state jump to normal
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Remove node a.b.c.198 from pending replacing endpoint
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 4] compaction - Compacted 2 sstables to [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1624-big-Data.db:level=0, ]. 18365 bytes to 12119 (~65% of original) in 43ms = 0.27MB/s. ~256 total partitions merged to 1.
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 4] compaction - Compacting [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1612-big-Data.db:level=0, /var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1624-big-Data.db:level=0, ]
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - NORMAL: node is now in normal status
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] cdc - No generation seen during startup.
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting tracing
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - SSTable data integrity checker is disabled.
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting batchlog manager
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting load meter
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting cf cache hit rate calculator
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting view update backlog broker
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
Feb 16 05:24:53 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 4] compaction - Compacted 2 sstables to [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/mc-1636-big-Data.db:level=0, ]. 18198 bytes to 12115 (~66% of original) in 37ms = 0.31MB/s. ~256 total partitions merged to 1.
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] gossip - No gossip backlog; proceeding
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - allow replaying hints
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - Launching generate_mv_updates for non system tables
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting the view builder
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 1] compaction - Compacting [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/truncated-38c19fd0fb863310a4b70d0cc66628aa/mc-229-big-Data.db:level=0, /var/lib/scylla/data/system/truncated-38c19fd0fb863310a4b70d0cc66628aa/mc-217-big-Data.db:level=0, ]
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - starting native transport
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Starting listening for CQL clients on a.b.c.198:9042 (unencrypted)
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] storage_service - Thrift server listening on a.b.c.198:9160 ...
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - serving
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 0] init - Scylla version 4.1.7-0.20200918.2251a1c577 initialization completed.
Feb 16 05:25:05 e2e-71-39 scylla:  [shard 1] compaction - Compacted 2 sstables to [/var/lib/scylla/data/system/truncated-38c19fd0fb863310a4b70d0cc66628aa/mc-241-big-Data.db:level=0, ]. 10782 bytes to 5549 (~51% of original) in 50ms = 0.11MB/s. ~256 total partitions merged to 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore, for some reason, the firewall service in the node3 was not allowing any incoming traffic on Scylla port. Once the firewall service was restarted, node3 was able to connect to nodes 1 and 2 and join the cluster successfully.